# jcifs-ngのSmbFile#listFiles()で得られるファイルが実際と異なるもの（フルパスから直上の親ディレクトリが失われたもの）となる

Tags: android, samba, smb

jcifs-ngを利用してandroid端末からSMBサーバーに接続し、SmbFileクラスのlistFilesメソッドの結果を利用しようとすると「SmbException: The system cannot find the file specified」というエラーが出ました。
単純化した下記のコードで調べたら、最初のSmbFileインスタンスは正しいものの、listFiles().pathメソッドで得られる子ファイルのフルパスは、各ファイルの直上の親ディレクトリ（最初のSmbFileインスタンスのファイル名）が脱落していました。
listFiles()で得られるSmbFile型インスタンスも間違ったパスを保持しているものと思われます。
listFiles()で正しい結果を得る方法がわかりませんでしょうか。

##### MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import jcifs.CIFSContext
import jcifs.config.PropertyConfiguration
import jcifs.context.BaseContext
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.util.*
import kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
    // 認証情報
    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Please replace these values to your data //
    val user = "USER"
    val password = "PASS"
    val domain = "192.168.1.1"
    val smbroot = "smb://" + domain + "/smb/my/tmp"
    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    val TAG: String = "MySMB"

    // coroutine準備
    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + job

    // 終了時のcoroutineのキャンセル設定
    override fun onDestroy() {
        job.cancel()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val smb = connectSMB(user, password, domain, smbroot)
                Log.d(TAG, "Got SMB: " + smb.path)


                if (smb.isDirectory) {
                    for (eachFile in smb.listFiles()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "CASE1 " + eachFile.path)
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "CASE2 " + smb.path)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun connectSMB(user: String, password: String, domain: String, smbroot: String): SmbFile {
        lateinit var smb: SmbFile
        coroutineScope {
            smb = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val prop = Properties()
                prop.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.minVersion", "SMB202")
                prop.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.maxVersion", "SMB300")
                val bc = BaseContext(PropertyConfiguration(prop))
                val creds = NtlmPasswordAuthentication(bc, domain, user, password)
                val auth: CIFSContext = bc.withCredentials(creds)
                SmbFile(smbroot, auth)
            }.await()
        }
        return smb
    }
}
```

##### Logcat出力

```
2021-08-13 18:33:56.249 18700-18700/PACKAGE.PROJECT.smbclient D/MySMB: Got SMB: smb://192.168.1.1/smb/my/tmp
2021-08-13 18:33:57.807 18700-18914/PACKAGE.PROJECT.smbclient D/MySMB: CASE1 smb://192.168.1.1/smb/my/file2
2021-08-13 18:33:57.807 18700-18914/PACKAGE.PROJECT.smbclient D/MySMB: CASE1 smb://192.168.1.1/smb/my/file1
2021-08-13 18:33:57.808 18700-18914/PACKAGE.PROJECT.smbclient D/MySMB: CASE1 smb://192.168.1.1/smb/my/tmp1/
2021-08-13 18:33:57.808 18700-18914/PACKAGE.PROJECT.smbclient D/MySMB: CASE1 smb://192.168.1.1/smb/my/tmp2/
```

smb/my/tmp/file2がsmb/my/file2と、smb/my/tmp/file1がsmb/my/file1と、smb/my/tmp/tmp1/がsmb/my/tmp1/と、smb/my/tmp/tmp2/がsmb/my/tmp2/と、誤った出力となっている。

##### 実際のファイル構成

smb/my/
　└─tmp
　　　│
　　　├── file1
　　　├── file2
　　　├── tmp1/
　　　└── tmp2/

Answer (score 1):

以下ページの記述を参考に修正したところ、正しい出力を得られました。

https://javadoc.io/static/eu.agno3.jcifs/jcifs-ng/2.0.3/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html

> all SMB URLs that represent workgroups, servers, shares, or directories require a trailing slash '/'.

**変更前:**

```
val smbroot = "smb://" + domain + "/smb/my/tmp"
```

**変更後:**

```
val smbroot = "smb://" + domain + "/smb/my/tmp/"
```